# bootstrap grid system push up boxes / fluid grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

*// sorry for my bad english*

I have a website with product boxes, and i want to make the boxes vertically push to each other, a fluid grid page with bootstrap.

> Note: My bootstrap css have **24** columns instead **12**!

**Source code:**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <span>item price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <span>item price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="4.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <span>item price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="5.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <span>item price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="6.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <span>item price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="7.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <span>item price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="8.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <span>item price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="9.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <span>item price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-6:nth-child(4n+1){
    clear: left;
}
```

Now my page looks like this:
http://i58.tinypic.com/2rcwsh4.png

I want something like this:
http://i60.tinypic.com/2vdie50.jpg

This is possible?

Comment: If you use row no!   row mean keep all the elment inside on row

Comment: For this i suggest that you use http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thats what i want! Thank you! :)